# In Spark JobServer. How to pass a json formated string on the input.string?

Tags: json, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Im trying to execute the following curl command to run a job:

```
curl -k --basic --user 'user:psw' -d 'input.string= {"user":13}' 'https://localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=test.ImportCSVFiles&context=import&sync=true'
```

But I get the following error:

```
 "com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: String: 1: input.string has type OBJECT rather than STRING"
```

My idea is to pass more than one parameter like an sql query. A json format to easy handling on my submitted jar.

I'm on the right way or there is another way?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, but exception is pretty clear. {"user":13} is a json object, and "input.string" wants to except a string value. So send it as string escape quotes if necessary, and internally convert that string to json

Comment: @AbhishekAnand that is what I have also tried but if I use `"input.string = {\"user\":13}"` I get the same result and using `"input.string = \{\"user\":13\}"` then  _Reserved character '\\' is not allowed outside quotes_. From my point of view _{"user":13}_ is a string, it have json format? Yes, but it is an string.

Comment: did you try 'input.string= \"{\"user\":13}\" '

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Thanks that works!!! One more question, the **input.string** it is a reserved word? Can be used like **input.json** or something else can be done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying it from comment.

Issue was json was trying to read it not as string but as object directly because of string starting with braces "{".

Correct input `'input.string= \"{\"user\":13}\" '`

Answer (score 1):

input.string is not a reserved keyword -- in fact, you can name the parameters arbitrarily. Let say, you POST two parameterss foo.string and foo.number. You then read the parameters in your SJS job, like this:

```
 // run is the starting point of a SJS job (also see validate function)
 override def runJob(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): Any = {
  val cmd = config.getString("input.cmd") 
  val fooString = config.getString("foo.bar")
  val fooNum    = config.getInt("foo.number")
```

Just in case you plan to execute SJS jobs from Scala/Java:

Apache Commons Lang (org.apache.commons.lang3) comes with a very helpful class to escape JSON: StringEscapeUtils

I use it to escape inputs from my Scala application that I need to pass to SparkJobServer jobs, like this:

```
input.schema=\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(referenceSchema)+"\""
```

referenceSchema is a JSON document (in my case a JSON array)

input.schema is then one of many comma-separated parameters in the body of HTTP post from Scala...